# Why does the red heart emoji require two code points, but the other colored hearts require one?

Tags: unicode, emoji, codepoint

It appears that the red heart emoji (❤️) "\u2764\uFE0F" requires two Unicode codepoints, specifically [Heavy Black Heart](https://codepoints.net/U+2764) followed by a [Variation Selector](https://codepoints.net/U+FE0F). However, [blue](https://codepoints.net/U+1F499) , [green](https://codepoints.net/U+1F49A) , [yellow](https://codepoints.net/U+1F49B) , and [purple](https://codepoints.net/U+1F49C)  each have their own single codepoint.

Why is red so different?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

For historical reasons. Originally, there was only U+2764 HEAVY BLACK HEART which the first applications that supported Emojis decided to render as a red heart. These early applications always rendered U+2764 as Emoji. Later it was realized that this was a bad idea and the variation selectors for Emojis were standardized. When additional heart emojis were added, there was no need for another red heart, so it was omitted. Instead there's a separate black heart emoji U+1F5A4 .

In theory, an application could require that the Emoji variation selector is appended to other heart code points as well. But it doesn't make much sense to render characters like PURPLE HEART as a non-Emoji. It does make a difference for HEAVY BLACK HEART, though, which is often intended to be rendered as the original, plain heavy black heart character.

Comment: Pretty sure that the other color hearts — okay, _most_ of them, that is, not the black emoji heart — were in the first round of emoji, but only 2764 was defined as an interpretation of an existing symbol. (Well, that's true avoiding card suits, at least.)

Answer (score 35):

HEAVY BLACK HEART was added to Unicode decades before emoji. When emoji were incorporated in Unicode 6 some already existing characters were simply reused as emoji to avoid unnecessary duplicates. Later, variation sequences were defined for characters that also map to a non-emoji character set to allow for better control over how they display. For example, U+2744 ❄ SNOWFLAKE is originally from Zapf Dingbats (I believe) but was later also made an emoji. So if you want to force the original text-style display you can use VARIATION SELECTOR-15 (resulting in ❄︎), and if you want to force the newer emoji-style display you can use VARIATION SELECTOR-16 (resulting in ❄️).

Note, however, that not many platforms actually support those variation sequences correctly at the moment. Also not all of them automatically apply the variation selectors when using the emoji keyboard. In theory ❤ and ❄ (and [many other emoji](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%3AEmoji%3A%5D%26%5B%3A%5EEmoji_Presentation%3A%5D&g=&i=)) should display as text style by default without VS16, but many applications ignore that as well.

[I have a list of all code points that can display differently via a variation sequence, on my website, if you're interested](http://randomguy32.de/unicode/charts/standardized-variants/#emoji). The next Unicode update in June is going to add some more.

Comment: Note: Zapf Dingbats (the font) ≠ Dingbats (the Unicode section)