# How to print red heart in python 3

Tags: python, unicode, emoji

I need to print the red heart emoji ❤️️ with unicode in Python 3 but it has two unicodes (\U00002764 and \U0000FE0F). How am I suppose to print it?

For example, a green heart is `print("\U0001F49A")`

Comment: enjoy all python emojis including red heart and even green heart  https://medium.com/@codingpilot25/how-to-print-emojis-using-python-2e4f93443f7e

Comment: Why not just include the emoji itself in your code, rather than escape it?

Comment: It's a composite character, so you print both, for example `print(c1 + c2)`.

Comment: I really appreciate this question. +1 ❤️️

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> print("\u2764\ufe0f")
❤️
```

Whether it "works" depends on the font you have and which glyphs it supports. Here's the same character in a non-code font (literally copy/pasted from the above):

> ❤️

In some more detail, [U+2764](https://html.duckduckgo.com/html?q=u%2B2764) is `HEAVY BLACK HEART` and typically renders as a black heart: ❤

[U+FE0F](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fe0f/index.htm) is `VARIATION SELECTOR 16` which is a combining character which modifies the previous character, in this case to turn the heart red.

Neither of these code points has more than four hex digits so using the long-hand `\U00000000` form is unnecessary.

(For what it's worth, in the text above, I see a black heart in the code font, and a red one in the regular body text font. In the MacOS Terminal, the red heart renders in a different font, so there I see it as a red heart in the Python REPL, too.)

[image: Screen shot showing how the character renders, MacOS Catalina]

Comment: For what it's worth, in the mobile version of this site, I see a red heart in the code block, too (Firefox on iPhone). But then it renders the undecorated U+2764 glyph as a red heart, too.

Answer (score 8):

Neither of the two unicodes worked for me - they both printed black hearts. The red heart requires combining the two unicodes:

```
print("\u2764\uFE0F")
```

Explanation for why it requires two unicodes can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42679712/why-does-the-red-heart-emoji-require-two-code-points-but-the-other-colored-hear).

Comment: It only printed a black heart for me. What IDE are you using? I can try using that IDE

Comment: I tried it on Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.6. It also worked directly on my terminal by opening a python3 environment.