# Finding ord of a red heart giving errors Python

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to print the ord  of a red heart in Python.
I have checked [How to print red heart in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64161291/how-to-print-red-heart-in-python-3) but it is not related to ord function.

When I tried `print(ord(❤️))` I have received the following error:

```
  File "testord.py", line 1
    print(ord(❤️))
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid character '❤' (U+2764)
```

I am not getting what to do to get the `ord` of the red heart. I have tried searching the ord value online and I got `9829`. But when I am trying to print it or send it to Messenger it is giving a white or colorless sort of heart.

Please any one can tell me what to do with this situation?

Comment: Also I forgot to mention I am getting boxes instead of heart which I understood that may be because of the encoding of the CMD. But still do not have any answer.

Comment: `"❤️"`?! You can't just put random characters in the code, that's not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 3):

You should at least use quotes around a string: `print(ord('❤️'))`. That would be enough to get rid of your current error.

But you would fall into a different one, because your *character* is actually composed from 2 characters: U+2764 ('HEAVY BLACK HEART'), U+FEOF ('VARIATION SELECTOR-16'). To correctly get its codes, you should use:

```
print([hex(ord(i)) for i in '❤️'])
```

to get:

```
['0x2764', '0xfe0f']
```

(I used `hex` because I prefere to follow unicode usage of hexadecimal)